# why my wordpress get the thumbnail don't return my custom size?

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I don't understand why my custom thumbnail size doesn't work good

I check the developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail
and do this in my function.php page :

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {    
        add_image_size( 'full-size', 9999, 9999 );          // full size
        add_image_size( 'septcent', 700, 9999 );            // sur accueil    
        add_image_size( 'principal', 800, 9999 );           // general
  
        add_image_size( 'artiste', 400, 400, true );        // icon artiste
        add_image_size( 'artiste-page', 800, 300, true );   // icon artiste
        add_image_size( 'gd-slider', 9999, 640 );       // pour grand sliders   

        add_image_size( 'grandes-img', 1200, 9999 );     // pour grandes images 
        add_image_size( 'sup-gds-img', 1800, 9999 );     // pour grandes images 
};
```

and call it in my page like that

```
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'septcent' ); ?>
```

but this return a thumbnail that fit on the screen with the 700px width but load a 1536px size

when I inspect my code I see the image link is here in the srcset create by the wordpress loop

[image]

[*(my test page)*](https://quentinrenaux.com/thisissansimages/)

**What's I'm doing wrong ?**

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have another plugin that loads all version of your images.
some of the SEO and Caching Plugins make it for Good SEO and Page speed result.

if u wanna check your code, I prefer to disable all plugin first, then u can see the pure and right result.

Comment: Hello @james there are all disable except Yoast and an SLL plugin, and I regenerate my thumbnail again to see if it's from this

Answer (score 0):

it's seems all of this is from the srcset and if you use retina your screen need more pixels to display the img therefor it will load the biggest resolution to match with it.

I don't have more information on the resolution that need and would know more about it, but for this google is my friends.